# Is there a way to get all Class elements without for-loop?

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, dom

So I want to get all class elements by document.getElementsByClassName();

```
<body>
    <div class="circle" id="red"></div>

    <div class="circle" id="blue"></div>

    <div class="circle" id="yellow"></div>

    <input id="disappear" type="button" value="disappear" onclick="disappear()">
  </body>

<script>
     function disappear(){
       document.getElementsByClassName(".circle").style.display = none;
     }
</script>
```

I want to let those circles disappear with `document.getElementsByClassName(".circle").style.display = none;`

This doesn't work so I used

```
function disappear(){
            var x, i;
            x = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");
              for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";
              }
        }
```

My question is, is there a way to select all classes without a loop?

Comment: If you have a collection of independent elements you have to modify each element separately. You could wrap them all in another element and hide this parent element instead: `<div id="place-for-all-my-circles"><div class="circle"></div>/*...*/</div>` + `document.querySelector("#place-for-all-my-circles").style.display = "none"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need a loop to iterate the items. However, `Document.querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList, and you can use `NodeList.forEach()` (still a loop) to iterate the elements and hide them:

```js
function disappear() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".circle").forEach(el => el.style.display = 'none');
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="circle" id="red">1</div>

  <div class="circle" id="blue">2</div>

  <div class="circle" id="yellow">3</div>

  <input id="disappear" type="button" value="disappear" onclick="disappear()">
</body>
```

Comment: I would add a class hidden (where hidden is `.hidden { display:none}`) to each element instead of altering css from js. Good answer nevertheless

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using jQuery, you can do:

```
$(".circle").css("display", "none");
```

Or, even shorter:

```
$(".circle").hide();
```

Comment: Where did you find jQuery in the question or the tags?

Comment: Well, the OP didn't mention they only want vanilla JS.

Comment: Oh nice! That's useful!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the build in array map function

```
function disappearListener(){
   var circles = document.getElementsByClassName("circle");
   circles.map(circle=>{
      circle.style.display = none;
      //or
      circle.classList.add('.hideCircle');
   })
 }

 var disappearButton = document.getElementById("disappear");
 disappearButton.addEventListener('click',disappearListener)
```

On CSS file

```
.hideCircle {
   display: none;
}
```